# Test angular-translate fallbackLanguage

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to understand if it would be possible to do some kind of test (unit/e2e) on the translation files sent to angular-tranlsate to check if some keys are accidentally not translated.

Let say I have
fr.json:

```
key1 : 'ma première chaîne',
key2 : 'ma deuxième chaîne',
key3 : 'ma troisième chaîne',
key4 : 'ma quatrième chaîne'
```

and en.json:

```
key1 : 'my first string',
key2 : 'my second string',
key4 : ''
```

Note the missing 'key3' in en.json and the empty value for 'key4'

So, let say I define fr.json as the fallbackLanguage, I would want to test the 'en.json' to see if it misses some keys (that are going to the fallbackLanguage) and the empty values.

Thanks for any help or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an `angular-translate` option. [See here](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/08_fallback-languages).

```
$translateProvider
  .translations('de', { /* ... */ })
  .translations('en', { /* ... */ })
  .fallbackLanguage('en');
```

**EDIT :**

To check manually if you have missing keys, you can do, for example :

```
$q.all([
  $http.get('/path/to/fr.json'),
  $http.get('/path/to/en.json')
]).then(function (results) {
  var fr = results[0],
      en = results[1],
      i;

  for (i in fr) {
    if (!fr.hasOwnPropery(i)) { continue; }
    if (!(i in en)) {
      console.log(i + 'is in fr but not in en');
    }
  }

  for (i in en) {
    if (!en.hasOwnPropery(i)) { continue; }
    if (!(i in fr)) {
      console.log(i + 'is in en but not in fr');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already know about the fallbackLanguage method.  What I want is a way to test if every keys for a certain language are there in the file.  Is it a good practice to test that or just double check the file is the way to go?